# How can you change TextField state based on input in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, combine

I'm pretty new to SwiftUI, so I'd love any help!

I'm looking to build a `TextField` that shows an error state based on the validation of the `text`.

For example, if the `TextField` is meant to collect an email, show an error if the `text` doesn't contain `@`. Let's say the error state would change the border color of the `TextField` to `Color.green`.

I was thinking of approaching this with a validating closure, but I'm still unsure of how to change the actual visual state of the `TextField`.

I see that we can [can change border color based on editing state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379010/how-to-change-swiftui-textfield-style-after-tapping-on-it) - should I just declare something like a `@State var isError`?

I've also tried holding `TextFieldStyle` as a `@State`, but that seems to be a protocol with an associated type, which I haven't been able to get around:

Something like:

```
TextField("",
              text: $text,
              onEditingChanged: { _ in
                self.style = CustomErrorStyle()
```

Please let me know if I can clarify at all, thanks!

Comment: And how do you want it *shows an error state*?

Comment: @Asperi Let's say that the border color changes to `Color.green`, as an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64683684/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Yes, I think so, thank you! I was thinking of using a `@State`, like I mentioned in the question. I'll try that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $text value will be constantly updated, so you can just update the TextField formatting based on the current value of text. Here is a sample:

```
struct TextFieldTest: View {
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
            .padding()
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                    .stroke(
                        text == "" ?
                        Color.gray :
                        textIsAppropriate() ?
                        Color.green :
                        Color.red
                        , lineWidth: 2.0)
            )
    }
    
    func textIsAppropriate() -> Bool {
        if text.contains("@") {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Of course, the solution in @Asperi's comment above also works if you prefer to only change the formatting when a user taps a button!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, although @Asperi's answer is teaching me as well!